# Why does using ActionListener break my Swing Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have an application working in Java Swing, but can't seem to convert to an Applet. Basically there are four buttons displayed on the Applet, and I want one of them to clear the screen and then draw a new interface (I'm going to add stuff for the other buttons, of course, but I got stuck here).

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet; //import swing applet interface
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class TopMenu extends JApplet{ 

  private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

  public void init(){
            mainMenu(); 
  }

public void mainMenu() {

    // create buttons

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    JButton collectButton = new JButton("Collect data");
    JButton uploadButton = new JButton("Upload");
    JButton downloadButton = new JButton("Download");
    JButton exploreButton = new JButton("Explore data");

    panel.add(collectButton);
    panel.add(uploadButton);
    panel.add(downloadButton);
    panel.add(exploreButton);

    collectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(  ) {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          int numberGFish = 400;
                //panel.removeAll();  
                        //panel.add(new JLabel("Just to test"), BorderLayout.CENTER);   
                        //panel.revalidate();   
                        //panel.repaint();   
            }
    });

    setContentPane(panel);

  }

}
```

All the code works totally fine until I add the ActionListener, and then the whole thing just goes blank. It compiles okay, but when I test it on my server not even the first menu comes up, it's just a blank panel. I've tried putting loads of really banal things in the ActionListener bit to make sure it's not a problem with them, but as you can see even just declaring a number in there doesn't work.

Originally I actually had the Listener bit call on another method which then did everything else, and that didn't work either, I scrapped that because I thought perhaps that was the problem.

I'm sure this is so simple but I've sunk many hours into it now and I've really just run out of ideas of things to test. And advice gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Works totally fine for me. I used the exact code you posted, even using the commented code, and the button works fine.

Comment: Oh gosh how strange. I'm hosting it on my server here http://chrisbeeley.net/website/java-demo.html It's an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server and I'm using Chrome on Linux Mint to test it. As I say it renders fine with the ActionListener removed, but is blank with it added. How weird that my code actually works. Thanks for letting me know, I'll try it on another browser. If anybody does click the link I'd be very grateful to know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it would be a problem or not but all GUI components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Here is the recommended code structure from the Swing tutorial on How to Make Applets:

```
public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete");
    }
}

private void createGUI() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(
                       "You are successfully running a Swing applet!");
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.black));
    add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was a dumb question, but I just couldn't figure it out. I've sorted it now.

I was being totally daft and not copying across the TopMenu$1.class file to the server. For some reason it works without this file but not with the ActionListener bit added. So I never thought that could be the problem.

Doh! Thanks all.